# Count the rows of SQL statement with Group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count the rows of SQL statement with GROUP BY. 
Here is my sql statement:

[I want to get the count of these rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mas1V.png)

```
SELECT RETAILER_ID, COUNT(RETAILER_ID) AS TOTAL 
FROM ret_retailer 
LEFT JOIN temp_sg_screen_sto_72_mos_summary ON ret_retailer.RETAILER_FULL_NAME = temp_sg_screen_sto_72_mos_summary.RETAILER_NAME 
WHERE MAY_2018 < 100000  
GROUP BY RETAILER_ID
```

Comment: What do you mean by `3738 count`?

Comment: So you wnat to count all the possible different RETAILER_ID ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay please see my sql What I want is to get the row count out the result of my sql statement

Comment: As I understrand, you wanna to get count of all returned rows? as your example, you expect to get 3738?

Comment: @Muhammadvakili yes sir

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
select count(*)
from (
-- insert your query here
) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r.RETAILER_ID)
FROM ret_retailer r LEFT JOIN
     temp_sg_screen_sto_72_mos_summary s
     ON r.RETAILER_FULL_NAME = s.RETAILER_NAME 
WHERE MAY_2018 < 100000  ;
```

The only difference from your results if if `RETAILER_ID` could ever be `NULL`.  It is easy enough to adjust for `NULL` values, but I'm guessing that it is never `NULL`.